# CASE Statement - An expression services limit has been reached

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm getting the following error:

> An expression services limit has been reached. Please look for potentially complex expressions in your query, and try to simplify them.

I'm attempting to run the below query, however it appears there is one line too many in my case statement (when i remove the "London" Line, it works perfectly) or "Scotland" for example.

I can't think of the best way to split this statement.
If i split it into 2 queries and union all, it does work. however the `ELSE 'No Region'` becomes a problem. Everything which is included in the first part of the query shows as "No Region" for the second part of the query, and vice versa.

(My end goal is essentially to create a list of customers per region) I can then use this as the foundation of a regional sales report.

Many Thanks

Andy

```
SELECT T0.CardCode, T0.CardName, T0.PostCode,
  
  CASE
WHEN T0.PostCodeABR IN  ('DG','KW','IV','PH','AB','DD','PA','FK','KY','G','EH','ML','KA','TD') THEN 'Scotland' 
WHEN T0.PostCodeABR IN  ('BT') THEN 'Ireland' 
WHEN T0.PostCodeABR IN  ('CA','NE','DH','SR','TS','DL','LA','BD','HG','YO','HX','LS','FY','PR','BB','L','WN','BL','OL') THEN 'North M62' 
WHEN T0.PostCodeABR IN  ('CH','WA','CW','SK','M','HD','WF','DN','HU','DE','NG','LN','S') THEN 'South M62' 
WHEN T0.PostCodeABR IN  ('LL','SY','LD','SA','CF','NP') THEN 'Wales' 
WHEN T0.PostCodeABR IN  ('NR','IP','CB') THEN 'East Anglia' 
WHEN T0.PostCodeABR IN  ('SN','BS','BA','SP','BH','DT','TA','EX','TQ','PL','TR') THEN 'South West' 
WHEN T0.PostCodeABR IN  ('LU','AL','HP','SG','SL','RG','SO','GU','PO','BN','RH','TN','ME','CT','SS','CM','CO') THEN 'South East' 
WHEN T0.PostCodeABR IN  ('ST','TF','WV','WS','DY','B','WR','HR','GL','OX','CV','NN','MK','PE','LE') THEN 'Midlands' 
WHEN T0.PostCodeABR IN  ('WD','EN','HA','N','NW','UB','W','WC','EC','E','IG','RM','DA','BR','CR','SM','KT','TW','SW') THEN 'London' 

ELSE 'No Region'

END AS 'Region'
   FROM [dbo].[REPS-PostcodeABBR] T0
```

Comment: That `CASE` **expression** doesn't look particularly complex to me. Why don't you, however, just create a "look up" table and `JOIN` to that?

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use single quotes for identifiers such as column aliases. Yes, sadly SQL Server accepts that, but in SQL single quotes are usually for string (or date...) literals. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future SQL Server versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an error. Use square brackets for identifiers that have special characters in them or are case sensitive or preferably don't use special characters and case sensitive identifiers at all. Identifiers don't need to be "pretty", "pretty" headers and such are a job for the presentation layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, I would suggest you create a "lookup" table for the post codes, then all you need to do is `JOIN` to the table, and not have a "messy" and large `CASE` **expression** (T-SQL doesn't support `Case` (`Switch`) statements).

So your lookup table would look a little like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.PostcodeRegion (Postcode varchar(2),
                                 Region varchar(20));
GO
--Sample data
INSERT INTO dbo.PostcodeRegion (Postcode,Region)
VALUES('DG','Scotland'),
      ('BT','Ireland'),
      ('LL','Wales');
```

And then your query would just do a `LEFT JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT RPA.CardCode,
       RPA.CardName,
       RPA.PostCode,
       COALESCE(PR.Region,'No Region') AS Region
FROM [dbo].[REPS-PostcodeABBR] RPA --T0 is a poor choice of an alias, there is no T not 0 in "REPS-PostcodeABBR"
     LEFT JOIN dbo.PostcodeRegion PR ON RPA.PostCodeABR = PR.Region;
```

Note you would likely want to `INDEX` the table as well, and/or apply a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` or `PRIMARY KEY` to the `PostCode` column.

Comment: I just wrote almost the same... So just one little addendum to your answer: Another advantage of a lookup table is that it's also reusable. You [the OP] don't need to repeat the `CASE` expression in similar queries or amend them all when something in the region assignment changes.

Comment: Correct, @stickybit , they scale very nicely, unlike a *very* large `CASE` expression. :)

Comment: The database i am writing into is a SAP Database, I've never actually Inserted into this table directly, nor have i previously created a table inside this database.
I've always been under the impression creating tables in a SAP database isn't permitted by their support... If this is the case i'm limited. (Unless i create a table using a front end editor such as B1up (which writes to the database and creates tables using SAPs DI API) -

This would be a visual editable table. (It could also be tiered, so i could click into "London" and drop a new postcode in that specific sub-table.) Thanks

Comment: I can't comment on SAP databases, I have never used them, @AndrewGray .

Comment: @AndrewGray - if you can't create an actual table you can do much the same with a [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-specifying-multiple-values-as-a-derived-table-in-a-from-clause) that should get over the  expression services limit though not give you something you can reuse in other queries

Comment: One could also create this lookup table in a "user" database (to avoid license restrictions and accidental loss from vendor updates) and simply join to it from the SAP database as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help... I tried multiple ways mentioned above, and they all did work, however the most efficient seemed to be this way.

Created a lookup table within SAP; This table included PostCodeFrom, PostCodeTo, PostCodeABR, Region

This would look like; TS00, TS99, TS, North M62

I then done;

`SELECT OCRD.ZipCode PCLOOKUP.Region, PCLOOKUP.PostCodeABR FROM OCRD T0 LEFT OUTER JOIN PCLOOKUP ON OCRD.ZipCode >= PCLOOKUP.PostCodeFROM AND OCRD.ZipCode <= PCLOOKUP.PostCodeFrom`

Basically, if the postcode is between
FROM AND To Display the abbreviation and region.